# Visual Basic Powershell query Server Pending Reboot status

Tags: vb.net, powershell, status, reboot

I am new to VB.net & Powershell.
Never the less I am programming an application which querys the PendingReboot status of our Win2012 Servers. 
There is this wonderful script which I implemented into my programm which does exactly that:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542

This is the code I use from Zainnab, to get access from VB2010.net to Powershell an return the result as a string.

```
'Takes script text as input and runs it, then converts
    'the results to a string to return to the user
    Private Function RunScript(ByVal scriptText As String) As String
    'create Powershell runspace
    Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

    'open it
    MyRunSpace.Open()

    ‘ create a pipeline and feed it the script text
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()

    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText)

    ‘ add an extra command to transform the script output objects into nicely formatted strings
    ‘ remove this line to get the actual objects that the script returns. For example, the script
    ‘ "Get-Process" returns a collection of System.Diagnostics.Process instances.
    MyPipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String")

    ‘ execute the script
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()

    ‘ close the runspace
    MyRunSpace.Close()

    ‘ convert the script result into a single string
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()

    For Each obj As PSObject In results
        MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
    Next

    ‘ return the results of the script that has
    ‘ now been converted to text
    Return MyStringBuilder.ToString()

End Function
```

#

```
    Try

        ‘ Create an instance of StreamReader to read from our file.
        ‘ The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(filename)

        ‘ use a string builder to get all our lines from the file
        Dim fileContents As New StringBuilder()

        ‘ string to hold the current line
        Dim curLine As String = ""

        ‘ loop through our file and read each line into our
        ‘ stringbuilder as we go along
        Do
            ‘ read each line and MAKE SURE YOU ADD BACK THE
            ‘ LINEFEED THAT IT THE ReadLine() METHOD STRIPS OFF
            curLine = sr.ReadLine()
            fileContents.Append(curLine + vbCrLf)
        Loop Until curLine Is Nothing

        ‘ close our reader now that we are done
        sr.Close()

        ‘ call RunScript and pass in our file contents
        ‘ converted to a string
        Return fileContents.ToString()

    Catch e As Exception
        ‘ Let the user know what went wrong.
        Dim errorText As String = "The file could not be read:"
        errorText += e.Message + "\n"
        Return errorText
    End Try

End Function
```

......

```
Dim ausgabe2 As String
            ausgabe2 = RunScript(LoadScript("c:\FHServerStat\PS_PR.stat\60.2.ps1"))
------
```

- I managed to get it partially working.

How ever the problem which I encounter is, by executing the script in powershell the rusult is correct.

By executing the script through visual basic, SOME returned values are incorrect, but see for yourself:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzpT2.png)

Please help me out on this

Regards

Okun

Comment: No one has an answer to this issue?